# Definition different from declaration for constexpr static member

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

Consider the code

```
#include <iostream>

struct Foo
{
    constexpr static int n = 42;
};

const int Foo::n; // note const, NOT constexpr

int main()
{
    std::cout << Foo::n;
}
```

The definition of the static member is different from the in-class declaration, i.e. `const` is used instead of `constexpr`. Is the code above legal, and if yes, why? It compiles with both gcc and clang. It also compiles if we interchanged `const` and `constexpr` in the definition and declaration, respectively. I know that `constexpr` implies `const` on variables, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My two cents, while  looking at some documentation like [that one](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/cpp11-language#cpp11-constexpr).

Actually, it could be valid.

In fact, the difference between `constexpr` and `const` mainly relies into their purposes, but the former implies the latter as a side effect.

There is also a more subtle difference: `constexpr` is a *specifier*, while `const` is a *type qualifier*.

In particular:

> const’s primary function is to express the idea that an object is not modified through an interface

On the other side:

> constexpr’s primary function is to extend the range of what can be computed at compile time, making such computation type safe and also usable in compile-time contexts

Or even more concise from [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr):

> constexpr - specifies that the value of a variable or function can appear in constant expressions

Anyway it happens that:

> constexpr in front of a variable definition [...] implies const

So, even though the reason for which one should use `constexpr` instead of `const` is clear, and everybody tends to remember that:

> constexpr is not a general purpose replacement for const (or vice versa)

It's a fact that using `constexpr` you are actually saying that this member is implicitly `const` (also you have a set of more specific constraints on how that member can be defined).

Anyway, once defined, the member is nothing more than a data member having the `const` type qualifier (which can be used in constant expressions), that is what you are declaring out of your class.